# Proof of multinomial theorem.

Tags: multinomial-coefficients

I have this proof of multinomial theorem by induction from the Instructor's Solution Manual for *Probability and Statistics, 3rd Ed.* by DeGroot and Schervish (Addison Wesley/Pearson, 2002). The proof is this:

[image]

[image]

I can't understand what is done after $(S.1.5)$.

Please please help.

Thank you.